# Registration by phone number restrictions

Tags: validation, security, phone-number, restriction

In an application that allow to register by phone number, it should be allowed to register with same phone number only to one user or more?

Some times users loses their phone numbers, so mobile operator can give that numbers to another users. So, it could be that one person register with phone number, and after some time this phone number reached another person, and now this person want to register in our system, should we allow or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well your application will have no way of knowing that a phone number was transferred by the mobile service provider to some other user. If your application has hundreds of thousands of users or more, then this may be a valid concern, but for small applications this is not likely to happen.

As a precaution you can force your users to renter their current mobile phone number after every month or so

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing here
You should change your registration by phone number logic.
You have to check email and phone number combination should be unique.
So your problem will resolved.

Comment: But in facebook you can register with only phone number, without email.